# execute remote php file with argument/variable

Tags: php, linux, remote-access

I am trying to remotely run a script with a variable (i.e. "php go.php 1232") where go.php copies directory template as 1232 and moves 1232 to /www/client.

If I run command ("php go.php 1232") on the destination server, everything works fine.

When I run remote_go.php, using at least 5 different ways including shell_exec, exec, ssh2, phpseclib, etc, a folder is created in /root on remote_server, or errors.  Folder directory never gets copies to where it is supposed to go.

Trying to be simple.

Server 1 has "remote_go.php"

```
<?php
shell_exec('ssh root@987.65.43.21 sudo php /tmp/go.php 1232');
?>
```

(in this case "variable" 1232 does not work)

Server 2 - go.php

```
<?php
$var1 = $argv[1];
$prac_code = $argv[1];
$api = "_api";
$port = $prac_code . $api;
$source = "./api";
$dest = "./$port";
mkdir($dest, 0755);
foreach($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS) , RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item)
{
if ($item->isDir())
    {
    mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
  else
    {
    copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
}
sleep(2);
path_to_file = "./$port/config/constant.php";
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("XXXXX", $prac_code, $file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $file_contents);
exec('scp -r ' . $port . ' /www/client');
exec('rm -rf *_api') ?>
?>
```

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: Put all in your question, not inside comments.